# Asynctask not finished downloading before next method call

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a simple class that extends `AsyncTask` where I access a textfile on the web and extract content to `String tmpString`. All this is done in `doInBackground()`. Right after calling `execute();` I call method my own method `parseContent();` from another class that extract substrings from `tmpString`.

Now to the problem, when I run this code I get `tmpString = null`, meaning the content from the website is null but I know the content is retrieved by checking with `Log.d("--------INFO--------", inputLine);` that prints line by line from the source file. I suspect that the download is too slow before the next method call. It all works fine when I debug because the download had time to finish.

Using `execute().get();` works, but I read that this isn't an optimal solution especially since it's blocking the thread. Later on I'd like to add a progress bar for the download but combining this with `get()` won't work... apparently.

What I'd like to do is to call the next method only if the download is complete, how can I achieve this?

Code here:

```
public class AccessFile extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
    private String urlContent = "";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        URL url= null;
        url= new URL((String) params[0]);

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            assert url!= null;
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            url.openStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String inputLine = null;
        inputLine = in.readLine();

        while (inputLine != null){
            Log.d("--------INFO--------", inputLine);
            urlContent += inputLine;
            inputLine = in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();
        return "";
    }
}
```

I call this with:

```
AccessFile af = new AccessFile();
af.execute("Link here").get();
```

Comment: Override `onPostExecute()` as well and call your method from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
AccessFile af = new AccessFile()
{
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           //code which should be executed after task completion
     }

}; 
af.execute("link);
```

Comment: This sort of works, however there's a problem.
I call `af.execute();` in `onCreate()` in  MainActivity, on the next line i try `String someString = af.getParsedString()` which returns a string that has been parsed in onPostExecute() but i get `someString = null`. `onPostExecute()` works fine and the string has a value. It seems that the call order is somwehat wrong. The order seems to be `af.execute()->af.getParsedString()->onPostExecute()` instead of 
`af.execute()->onPostExecute()->af.getParsedString()`.

Comment: inside onPostExecute() , write a code which should be executed after `af.execute("link");  `

Comment: **on the next line i try String someString = af.getParsedString()** , Do it inside onPostExecute(). And you can Initialize `af = new AccessFile(){...` inside onCreate()